# Pushing a local Git repository into an specific folder in remote repository

Tags: git, git-bash, git-push

I am new to Git and learning it while working on my project.

I am wondering how to perform the below action:

- I have a local repo name "localxyz"
- localxyz has many sub folders and files, eg:

  - localxyz

    - local SubFolder
    - local SubFolder
    - local files...
- I now have a remote repository named "remote-xyz"
- My remote repository also has few subfolders and files, eg:

  - remote-xyz

    - remote subfolder 1
    - remote subfolder 2
    - remote files...

Now I want to upload all my files and subfiles of "**localxyz**" repo to "**remote subfolder 1**" of "**remote-xyz**" repository. And yes, I'm using Git Bash (command line).

Is this possible, or would someone give any equivalent suggestions?

Comment: No, it is impossible to do that. That's not how git works. It's not an arbitrary file copying utility.

Comment: You could clone/pull the folder on the remote machine, and then use symlinks to place the subfolders in the correct locations.